# Highcharts remove zoom feature

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Hello I am using Highcharts for displaying charts. The chart also uses zoom feature. I want to remove the zoom feature. Any ideas on what we can do to remove the zoom feature.

Comment: Isn't it disabled by default?  Set your `chart` options' `zoomType` to ""

Comment: Yes, disabled by default. http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart--zoomType

Comment: You can see it in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495655/highcharts-stockchart-remove-zoom-feature

Answer (score 5):

You can set the zoom level.

Under the chart element, you can use the `zoomType` property, and set the exact width and height as the original size. You could also try setting `enable: false` or setting the level to `null`.

More information can be found [on the API documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/).

Answer (score 2):

Simply attribute zoomtype property mentioned in chart.
I am sure if your chart is supporting zoom currently, then there must be zoomtypoe mentioned in its configuration.
Just set it to false.

chart:{
   zoomType : false
}

Answer (score -3):

open highstock.js file. get the line with bellow code

```
if(!c.rendered&&(c.zoomText=e.text(i.rangeSelectorZoom,o,d.plotTop-10).css(g.labelStyle).add(),p=o+c.zoomText.getBBox().width+5,n(c.buttonOptions,function(a,b){h[b]=e.button(a.text,p,d.plotTop-25,function(){c.clickButton(b,a);c.isActive=!0}
```

and replace with this code

```
if(2==3&&!c.rendered&&(c.zoomText=e.text(i.rangeSelectorZoom,o,d.plotTop-10).css(g.labelStyle).add(),p=o+c.zoomText.getBBox().width+5,n(c.buttonOptions,function(a,b){h[b]=e.button(a.text,p,d.plotTop-25,function(){c.clickButton(b,a);c.isActive=!0}
```

this works for me. I hope works for you too

Comment: Ver bad idea to editing compressed sources. Instead just use [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.zoomType) option.

Comment: OK, so it does. For this version. What happens when someone is using a different version? The options, most likely, will not change in tiny version numbers, where the underlying code might be very different.