# HighCharts.StockChart remove zoom feature

Tags: highcharts

We have a StockChart and it has a zoom below the graph.  Well, just look at the jsfiddle

http://tinyurl.com/lfvyx5n

I want it all except the bottom zoom bar and the zoom 1m 1year, etc. etc. and that date range selector.  These are on by default but how can I turn it off.

My other option was to convert to HighChart.Chart which then is not doing dates anymore :( :(.  I am just looking for a real quick option.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: If you take a look the docs you'll see that you just have to set `enabled` to `false` on everything you want to remove.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to disable `navigator` to remove the bottom bar and to disable `rangeSelector` to remove the zoom button :

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    ...
    rangeSelector : {
        enabled: false
    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: false
    }
    ...
});
```

Here a JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CgAnW/

Comment: With this I still get the scrolling bar at the bottom: https://jsfiddle.net/wikiux/53mczjd7/8/